# Uploaded files empty on Parse.com iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my app I upload audio file to parse. Most of the time the file is uploaded properly but few times the audio file uploaded is of 0 bytes. I am very sure about the files that they are not empty as all the audio files that got uploaded empty, plays fine in my app.

I would like to know if the files got uploaded, under what conditions Parse would save a 0 byte file?

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You better add your code to upload data.

Comment: This can happen if the upload fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things come to mind. First of all could you post the code to the upload? What is occurring is that the push connection is being lost so Parse gets a connection, sees nothing coming through the pipes and thinks to itself that its all there is to it. I haven't seen your code yet, but have you tried using blocks? or saveEventually?

Comment: There was no issue with the code. The issue was with the user not allowing microphone access into my app, and an empty buffer was getting written for the audio.

But I am glad I could see other possibilities like broken pipe also that may trigger this behaviour.

Comment: You can test for the access to the microphone, and than setup logic within the mic recording logic that would only allow recording to occur if the mic is enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I think I did just that. Since prefs:// has been discontinued, I had to settle down for just the checking part on iOS7 http://foundmysolution.blogspot.in/2013/10/ios-7-microphone-request.html

Comment: Thank you for posting that solution, Im going to Star this question and use it for reference later.